# cant figure out how to show number of years working (including years less than 4)

Tags: sql, sqlyog

I currently have this question and I'm trying to figure out how to fix the joined in the last four (4) years part of the query. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

question:
List all doctors, that are currently active doctors of the clinic, that are female and **joined in the last four (4) years**. Show the name of the doctor and the name of their supervisor.

current query:

```
SELECT  CONCAT(d.given, d.surname) AS Doctor_Name, 
CONCAT(s.given, s.surname) AS Supervisor_Name
FROM doctor d, doctor s
WHERE s.doctorid = d.supervisorid 
AND d.resigned IS NULL 
AND d.sex = 'f' 
AND YEAR(d.joined) > 2013
```

option 2

```
SELECT CONCAT(doc.given,' ',doc.surname) AS Doctor_Name, 
CONCAT(sup.given,' ',sup.surname) AS Supervisor_Name,
doc.sex, 
doc.joined
FROM doctor doc, doctor sup
WHERE sup.doctorid = doc.supervisorid 
AND doc.resigned IS NULL 
AND doc.sex = 'F' 
AND YEAR (doc.joined) >= YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 4 YEAR)
ORDER BY doc.joined
```

Comment: In what way are those queries giving incorrect results?  And why did you remove the code formatting on the SQL?

Comment: `YEAR(Getdate()) - YEAR(d.joined) >= 4`

Comment: d.joined >= Dateadd(y,-4,d.joined), but this will give you to the day accuracy instead of year part accuracy as above. Would depend on what you need.

Comment: Both of your queries work.  Check it out here: http://rextester.com/PSJX22877  Perhaps your data isn't actually what you think it is?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  
   CONCAT(d.given, d.surname) AS Doctor_Name, 
   CONCAT(s.given, s.surname) AS Supervisor_Name
FROM doctor d
JOIN doctor s
   ON s.doctorid = d.supervisorid 
WHERE 
   d.resigned IS NULL 
   AND d.sex = 'f' 
   AND DATEDIFF(YEAR,d.joined,GETDATE()) < 4
```

So the point here is that the

```
DATEDIFF(YEAR,d.joined,GETDATE()) < 4
```

will subtract the year of d.joined from GETDATE() so if joined is 2015-01-01 and GETDATE() returns 2017-01-01 the result will be 2.
If you rather want 4 years from now you would have to do

```
DATEDIFF(DAY,d.joined, GETDATE()) < 4*365
```

this is approximately correct but doesn't handle leap years well if we cross a century boundary or if the timeperiod is something else but 4 years.

Comment: While this can correct answer the question it's better to add a quick explanation how it works